# Daterangepicker, cannot select date range which is older than current date

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have a strange behaviour.

I can not select a daterange which is older than the current date.

My setup is:

```
 $('.rangepicker').daterangepicker({
            autoUpdateInput: false,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        });
```

But even when i just setup the default, it is not possible.

Here you see the behaviour:
http://screencast.com/t/Ag7WiiMhMg

Has anyone an idea why?

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: Try to change format with `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Comment: Try to bind with `id` `"#rangepicker"` then `class` `".rangepicker"`

Comment: on jsfiddle it works of course :(

Comment: the other suggestions didn't helped as well. but thanks anyway